# How to edit pdf in SharePoint online or PDF annotation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf

I want to edit PDF file in SharePoint online document library. I have uploaded PDF in document library and also edit fie and save in same location(Document Library).

Comment: Please, specify the use case you want to know more about. I mean, if you have a PDF file in a document library what's the next action? Do you want to open and edit it in the browser? Do you want to open it in the desktop app and save it automatically after all changes have been done? I think several ways can apply and different solutions can be told.

Comment: @jaloplo  : Yes next action will be like, once i upload PDF file in document library then i want to edit file and save in same library. it would be good if i can add text,remove text,high light text in PDF file.

Comment: @jaloplo
 Flow -->  Once i upload PDF file in doc library then file will go for approval, in this case if approver can add text for high lighting some text part. it is like PDF annotation.

Comment: Did you check to use a different format (Microsoft native format) like Microsoft Word for doing this kind of things? If you want to finally have a PDF file you can do it by using 3rd party applications like Nintex Workflow or Nintex Forms. Did you check them?

Comment: Yes i want to go with PDF only and i did not check with Nintex.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can edit the pdf files from SharePoint online with the recent integration of Adobe PDF cloud with Office 365. You need to deploy the Adobe PDF cloud integration with Office 365 plugin into your office 365 tenant.

For details implementation refer to the below article :

[SharePoint Online – O365: How to Edit PDF File in SharePoint Online library](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/edit-pdf-file-from-sharepoint-online-site/)